# Вспомогательный метод и измененный шаблон

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Во вью написал такую строчку `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Pass, "My")` где My - это определенный шаблон хранящийся в EditorTemplate. Pass - имеет тип стринг. Сам код шаблона прост:

```
@model string
@Html.Editor("BlaBla") - проверка запуска шаблона
```

Я ожидаю получить на выходе поле ввода и надпись "проверка запуска шаблона". Но в ответ получаю, только лишь надпись. А вместо поля ввода - пустота. Если, конечно заменить хелпер на `<input... >` тогда появится поле. Вопрос в том, почему в шаблоне не работает `@Html.Editor("BlaBla")` ведь он же по идее и создает инпут с именем БлаБла ?

upd

```
@model test.Models.viewmodel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Pass, "My")<br />
            @Html.Editor("Test")<br />
            <input type="submit" name="Send" />
        }
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.name)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.mail)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AnyNum)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Pass)<br />
        <br />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Класс viewmodel , который передается в качестве модели во вью не содержит свойства с именем Test, но при этом поле ввода все равно создается в обычной вьюхе при использовании `@Html.Editor("Test")`. Но в шаблоне, который принимает модель типа стринг (которая тоже не содержит свойства Test) - уже поле ввода `@Html.Editor("Test")` не создается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем так, метод `@Html.Editor("BlaBla")` попытается создать инпут для свойства, определенного в классе модели, а аргумент `BlaBla` задает имя этого свойства. Модель имеет тип `string`, класс `System.String` не содержит определения свойства `BlaBla`, поэтому значение не отображается.

В данном случае, для создания инпута с заданным именем и значением, нужно использовать функцию `TextBox`:

```
@Html.TextBox("BlaBla", Model)
```

(Учтите, что по умолчанию имя из `TextBox` будет объединено через точку с именем свойства из `EditorFor`. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно указать пустую строку третьим аргументом: `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Pass, "My", "")`.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но почему тогда этот хелпер работает в обычной вьюхе ? Если в обычной вьюхе , которой передается модель не содержащая свойство с именем Test написать `@Html.Editor("Test")` - тогда создается поле ввода в именем и ИД 'Test', а в шаблоне это  поле ввода не создается. Обновил свой вопрос